# Search for dynamic number of words in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .csv file with 1 column and 9999 rows, I have to write an algorithm to search for strings with specific words in it. So far I have code for fixed number of words (3 words in that case):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', encoding='cp1251',header=None)
search = input("searching for:  " )
search = search.lower().split()
df[0] = df[0].str.lower()
print (df[df[0].str.contains(search[0]) & df[0].str.contains(search[1]) & df[0].str.contains(search[2])])
```

Please advise, how can I make similar algorythm for dynamic number of words to search.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please provide an example of your data, the string you want to search for along with desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to enumerate each possible index in `search`. Instead, you can use use `reduce()` with the bitwise and (`&`) operator.

```
#from functools import reduce  # for python3 only
print(df[reduce(lambda a, b: a&b, (df[0].str.contains(s) for s in search))])
```